# How to run laravel scheduler in ubuntu server

Tags: laravel

I have setup a scheduled task to fire an artisan command like below:

```
 */
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\GoogleAdsCronJob',
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('googleads:cron')
        ->everyFiveMinutes()
        ->appendOutputTo(self::LOG_PATH);
}
```

Then the path in ubuntu server `/var/www/html/myproject` I ran the command:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/my-prject/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

eventually nothing happened ? Logs are not saying anything!

Comment: Can you run `schedule:run` to test it works?

Comment: yes it does work @Troyer